# Should Vote Lock time-limit be Extended?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, grace-period, locked-votes

I'm sure everyone had the experience where they up/down vote a answer/question and some event happens in which you would like to remove or change your vote. But the grace period is not very long, often an "edit" to the post is made or a comment is made in which improves the quality of that question or changes your view. For low rep users that need suggestive edits to do a fake edit to change their vote, often they are denied and the vote cannot be changed.

Do you think extending the grace period of votes be a good idea or a bad one? Or would it have consequences?

Comment: You can undo an vote after an edit was made to the post, also if a comment improves the quality of the question considerably chances are that should be edited into the question and you can undo the vote too. I don't see the actual problem here.

Comment: The locking itself is the bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

If an edit is made to a post on which you have already voted, the system allows you to change your vote.

I cannot imagine a situation where a comment "improves the quality of [a] question". Comments can't improve the quality of questions because they *are not part of questions*. If there's something truly useful in a comment that changes your view on a question or answer, it should be edited into the body of the post itself. And then, of course, you can change your vote.

As far as low rep users who want to change their vote, I'd have to hear some compelling argument that the current grace period is not long enough. I do a lot of clicking and then changing my mind. You can tell because nearly all of my comments have been edited at least once. Even given my hastiness (or is it indecisiveness?), I've never had a real problem with the voting time limit. I have full edit privileges, so I could do one of those little fake edits, but I can't think of any time I have ever had to do that. And if the situation really did arise, why not just make it a real edit?

Comment: Sometimes there is not enough information to make a real edit, also if edits are reviewed and the comments are not seen it appears the edit adds unintended information to the question.

Comment: Then there isn't enough information to change your vote. Maybe there's something I'm not getting—consider providing concrete examples.

Comment: Say the questioner adds information via comment and does not edit their answer. A user attempts to add that info into the original question and is denied.

Comment: I don't know what that has to do with voting. The quality of the answer still hasn't changed, because the edit was denied. The problem there is the denial of valid edits, not vote locking.

Comment: I see, I agree with that. I guess I'm merely talking about human error, such that if someone changes there mind after re-reading a post at the later date without an edit. Obviously yes, they should of read the post more carefully if they skimmed it. Basically if a user decides they want to change their vote after a re-evaluation of the post they are looking at (in which it was not edited).