# Feature suggest: any one can down cast a question/answer that you up casted

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I up cast an answer then found it is wrong, but I can't down cast it with 125 reputation. Obviously SO should allow you to down cast a question/answer that you just up casted.

Comment: You can click on the upvote button again to undo your upvote. The [*downvoting privilege*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) requires 125 reputation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always remove your vote by clicking the upvote button again as long as it's within the time limit. Note that even with enough reputation to downvote, you'd still have to change your vote within the time limit.

You can change your vote on a post after the time limit if it's been edited.

Your feature request would basically be a run-around of the 125 reputation requirement for downvoting. People who don't have enough reputation to downvote directly would simply upvote first and then downvote the post.

Comment: Now its too late, "You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited". Now the suggestion is to make this period longer, e.g. days------ why not never locked? Another suggestion is to undo miss-down votes, I click the down votes button many times to undo my up vote, now I don't know whether my down vote is recorded, I don't need to down vote.

Comment: @jw_ it's locked to prevent me to downvote your answer, then wait for MY answer to get some upvotes, and then remove my downvote (to get my rep back. My answer already does better than yours, so it'll continue to get upvotes)

Comment: @jw_ Extending or eliminating the grace period for changing your vote is also a duplicate proposal. Someone linked to a few of them here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297201/have-we-considered-these-ideas-to-be-used-with-instead-of-vote-lock-in

Comment: @BSMP do you know how to find my deleted questions? On the main site, it is "View more" then "deleted recent questions" but not here.